# Why wine VLC application is repeating many times on right click menu of any video?

Tags: wine, vlc, .desktop, appmenu

After installing VLC media player in `wine` whenever I right click any video `VLC media player 2.1.5` is appearing 3 times as shown in picture:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using Wine here ? VLC is available as a native application on Ubuntu....

Comment: Yeah I have reason, I was comparing video quality of both native and wine vlc.

Answer (score 0):

> I was comparing video quality of both native and wine vlc

One is the `wine` version of VLC and the other is the native one. As for the third one... you may have duplicate `.desktop` files.